# Django Rest Framework API filtering User interface - not displaying

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm creating filters for my models in Django Rest Framework. This is my filters.py.

```
class EmployeeListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
    serializer = EmployeeSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('id', 'employee_type', 'rfid_tag')
    search_fields = ('event_type', 'employee_status')
    ordering_fields = ('id', 'employee_type')
```

In the DRF documentation they have examples that look like this:
[image]

I've checked my syntax in the documentation examples and everything looks right, but mine looks like this: 
[image]

what do I need to do get the search and ordering options I've set to display like in the examples in the docs? Any help is greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

NOE (New Operator Error)

I made a mistake in the place of my filter settings first of all. Moved them to proper file (views.py). I also realized I was combining to different kinds of filter settings. Using DjangoFilterBackends - by setting the filter_fields - automatically creates the types of filters.

I had combined the SearchFilters setting and the OrderingFiltering setting.

Now I have this: [image]

Problem solved (and lesson learned).